# Ajeitar JS para calcular o tamanho de uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu fiz um site one-page e para calcular o tamanho das divs principais eu usei esse JS:

```
    function tamanhos(){
        $('#a, #b, #c, #d').css('min-height', $(window).height());
    }
    $(window).load(tamanhos);
    $(window).resize(tamanhos);
```

A questão é que com o `window` o site abre com as divs tudo esmagadas, ai depois que carrega tudo que ele coloca o tamanho certo.

Tenho alguma outra opção para calcular o tamanho das divs, mas que não quebre enquanto o site está carregando?

Eu quero que quando o site abra cada div tenha no minimo o tamanho da tela. O que acontece agora é que as divs abrem todas esmagadas e depois de um tempo elas ajustam pro tamanho correto.

HTML:

```
<div id='conteudo'>
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'></div>
<div id='c'></div>
<div id='d'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: não podes mostrar o código html?

Comment: Como você quer que fique? Tem como esconder as divs até o conteúdo carregar.

Comment: @bfavaretto editada

Answer (score 2):

> Eu quero que quando o site abra cada div tenha no minimo o tamanho da tela

Você pode conseguir isso colocando `height: 100%` nessas divs. Mas atenção: todos os elementos acima delas na hierarquia também precisam ter essa declaração.

Por exemplo, para este HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id='conteudo'>
      <div id='a'></div>
      <div id='b'></div>
      <div id='c'></div>
      <div id='d'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Você precisaria de:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
#conteudo {
   height: 100%;
}
#a, #b, #c, #d {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pode colocar um [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) ( tipo modal ) na tela e uma mensagem de carregando... com o restante tudo oculto `$('body').hide()`, e depois que o seu código javascript estiver terminado por ultimo você da um `$('body').show()`

Answer (score 0):

> O que acontece agora é que as divs abrem todas esmagadas e depois de
>   um tempo elas ajustam pro tamanho correto

Isso ocorre porque o js não foi carregado ainda, uma alternativa seria mostrar as divs quando o js fosse carregado ou fazer como o bfavaretto explicou.